# How to merge two ordered akka streams to save the order

Tags: scala, akka, streaming, akka-stream

Let's say we have two different ordered akka-stream sources:

```
  val source1: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(1, 12, 18))
  val source2: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(10, 20, 30))
```

How can we merge this sources, so they the resulted stream also will be ordered?

```
val mergedOrderedStream: Source[Int, NotUsed] = ???

  mergedOrderedStream.runForeach(println)
  // Expected output:
  //  1
  //  10
  //  12
  //  18
  //  20
  //  30
```

Comment: What would you expect in 'output' if one of `Source`'s contain fewer elements?

Answer (score 3):

You should use **Source#mergeSorted**:

```
  val source1: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(1, 12, 18))
  val source2: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(10, 20, 30))

  val mergedOrderedStream: Source[Int, NotUsed] = source1.mergeSorted(source2)

  mergedOrderedStream.runForeach(println)
  // prints
  //  1
  //  10
  //  12
  //  18
  //  20
  //  30
```